# Scrolling a div directly

Tags: javascript

I need to find a way to ensure that every time I press up or down, my div called question_text scrolls up or down (If it's visible).

The issue is that throughout my code, I temporarily replace this div with a loading animation, and when the visibility is reset it seems to take the focus off question_text.

I've attempted to use autofocus to keep it in focus, but changing the visibility seems to get in the way.

```
<div id="question_text" class="question-text" onblur="this.focus()" autofocus="true">
```

I've also used the below code to refocus it when the element is visible again, but the code doesn't seem to do anything despite there being no errors.

```
var element = document.querySelector('.question-text');
if (window.IntersectionObserver) {
  var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if (entries[0].intersectionRatio) {
      question_text.focus()
    }
  }, {
    root: document.body
  });
  observer.observe(element);
}
```

Is there someway to simply scroll the div directly whenever pressing up or down? 100% of the time those keys are pressed, that div needs to be scrolled.

I would really like to find a way to bypass the focus issues I'm having, but can't find any example of a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling it `element` and then trying to focus it using `question_text`.

Make these changes:

```
// changed this var to question_text
var element = document.querySelector('.question-text');
var question_text = document.getElementById('#question-text');
if (window.IntersectionObserver) {
  var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if (entries[0].intersectionRatio) {
      question_text.focus();
    }
  }, {
    root: document.body;
  });
  observer.observe(element);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but copying and pasting that code exactly returns "Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'."

Comment: If I change it from #question-text to question_text to define it by the ID instead of the class, it returns no error but still doesn't keep the focus on question_text once the visibility is toggled to hidden and back to visible.

Comment: Oh my goodness. Then you could use both, right? :D

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? I see how the code I posted was wrong. Originally I thought I was supposed to define the IntersectionObserver as its own element which is where my problem was, but even using your syntax it doesn't keep the focus on question_text, which is why I was trying to see if there's a way to bypass focus and scroll the div directly. Thank you for pointing out the mistake I made though, but it still doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I realized the problem was due to an unrelated variable. Marking answer correct, thank you.